# Quiz application?

Tags: android

i am building a quiz application for my project. i have different activity for different question. i used radio button for the answers. please how can i set a counter that will be adding the score to the initial score? and where should i define the counter? and how do i get response on each click on different layout?
here is what i have

```
package com.example.android.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

    enter code here

public class page1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
int score = 0;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page1);

    }
    public void pageTwo(View view) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this,page2.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
    public void ans(View view)
    {

        Toast.makeText(this,score,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
}
```

Comment: I recommand for you something else you don't want to create a whole new activity for each question. Create a single activity and use extra (see my answer) to get the strings (question sentence, answer 1,2,3,4..) and int (the correct choice), so you can update the project easily by adding new questions. You can also let questions order be random so the user don't memorize them all.

Comment: man could you imagine what the answer studio structure would look like with an activity for each qestion. yikes. go one step further....use firebase. then pull the question in, with the answer, with the possible answers. should be pretty easy to be honest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Use SharedPreferences to store an integer which is the score:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("data", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putInt("score", score);
editor.apply();
```

To get the score in another activity:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("data", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
int score = sp.getInt("score", 0); //0 for default if score do not exist.
```

However, the variable will still exist even if the user exited the app.

**Solution 2:**

Pass data between activities:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityName.this, NewActivityName.class);
i.putExtra("extra", score);
startActivity(i);
```

In the new activity:

```
int score = getIntExtra("extra", 0); //0 for default if score do not exist.
```

Using this method you won't save the score if the user exited the app.